# Regex to replace logging

Tags: java, regex

I would like to add stacktrace to error logging, so anywhere we have

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    something();
    logger.severe("oops");
    something();
}
```

I would like to have this:

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    something();
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"oops",ex);
    something();
}
```

The exception variable can be anything *ex,* e etc.

I created a regex, but it is quite slow and does not work as I expect.

Regex:

```
((?s:.)*catch\s*\(\s*Exception\s*(.+)\s*\)\s*\{(?s:.)*logger\.)severe\(((?s:.)*?)\);((?s:.)*)
```

Replace:

```
$1log(Level.SEVERE,$3,$2); $4
```

It replaces

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    something();
    logger.severe("oops");
    something();
} 
{
   logger.severe("oops2");
}
```

to

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    something();
    logger.severe("oops");
    something();
} 
{
   logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"oops2",ex); 
}
```

Comment: So you're writing code to replace code?  Does your development environment not include a find/replace all function?

Comment: No. I want to replace code with regex using it in the replace all command of my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lazy matchers instead of greedy ones. Refer to the java.util.regex.Pattern documentation to get more details.

Comment: yes, thanks I forgot to use lazy matcher by the "logger" word